# Nautilus and the Disk Utility in Ubuntu Doesn't Recognized Veracrypt Encrypted USBs

Tags: usb, nautilus, encryption, gnome-disk-utility, veracrypt

I am using the Nautilus files application and my issue is that Nautilus and the disk utility isn't recognizing the contents of a Veracrypt encrypted USB. The disk utility just describes the contents as "Unknown" and doesn't get listed in the Nautilus sidebar however I am able to successfully mount, read, and write to files on the USB when using Veracrypt and when using Nautilus and the disk utility in a Debian live USB.

For a test I encrypted another USB using Veracrypt with the following configuration:

1. Algorithm: AES
2. Key Hash algorithm: SHA-512
3. Filesystem type: Ext4
4. Quick format enabled
5. Selected the option saying that I will only mount the drive on Linux systems
   and the disk utility still described the USB contents as "unknown".

I ran the command *sudo badblocks -w -s -o error.log /dev/sdb* on the USB and I got the following output:

```
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0x55: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0xff: done
Reading and comparing: done
Testing with pattern 0x00: done
Reading and comparing: done
```

The error log file was empty and so I am at a lost to what's happening. Any ideas?

Ubuntu version: 20.04.1

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal behavior for a Veracrypt encrypted partition / drive. Linux does not recognize this partition / drive, it just detects that there's something.

Then you use Veracrypt to decrypt the partition / drive.
It mounts it as a normal partition / drive that can be seen by Nautilus and the whole OS.

That's even one of the points of encrypting a whole partition / device : if you don't know that it was encrypted, you might just think that it is damaged.

If you want to have a recognized partition / drive, even without mounting it, then you can rather reformat it to a known file system (let's say Ext4) and create an encrypted file on it.